# How to get character count from textarea when component mounts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I'm trying out react and in the application there are 2 pages. `Home` and `Details` page. When navigated from `Home` to `Details` page there is a character count section which displays the number of characters in `textarea`.The components are `functional`.

```
// textarea reference
const textareaEl = useRef(null);

// character count
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
    // some init functions.
    const length = textareaEl.current.value.length;
    setCount(length);
}, []);
```

Here the `length` const variable logs the length of characters in textarea, but is not setting the `count` using the `setCount()`.

But in other event,  the `count` is set in the `keyUp` event

```
// Handle keyup
const handle_key_up = (e) => {
    // console.log(e.target.value.length);
    setCount(previousState => {
        previousState = parseInt(e.target.value.length);
        return previousState;
    });
}
```

The `textarea` html is

```
<textarea ref={textareaEl} onKeyUp={handle_key_up} name="content" value={book.content} onChange={handleChange}></textarea>
```

Is the `useEffect` is the place to set the `count` variable.

**Update**
The place I got wrong is; there is an `init` function inside the `useEffect` hook. It's an async function. And it is what fills the textarea with words. So I called the character count setting part in the promise resolve part.

Comment: You should change the dependency array in `useEffect` to use the count variable.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAli Thanks for the reply. The part I went wrong was calling/setting the `count` without completing the `init functions`. The `init functions` actually fill the text area with words. So I called the `setCount()` inside that.

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
    // some init functions.
    const length = textareaEl.current.value.length;
    setCount(length);
}, [count]);
```

The second parameter in useEffect hook specifies when the hook is to be called. In this case, since you want to count the number of characters, you can specify the count state.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The part I went wrong was calling/setting the `count` without completing the `init functions`. The `init functions` actually fill the text area with words. So I called the `setCount()` inside that.